# How can I avoid double wrapping into Some in F#

Tags: f#

I have the following code:

```
let f g x = if x < 0 then None else Some(g x)
```

Along with `f` the `g` function may or may not return `Option` as well. Since `f` has it as generic and doesn't have any generic constraints I can end up having `Some(Some(z))` as a result. If fact all I want is either `None` or `Some(z)`. How can I avoid double wrapping (preferably without imposing constraints on `g`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
> let f g x = if x < 0 then None else Some(g x)

val f : g:(int -> 'a) -> x:int -> 'a option
```

`f` returns `'a option` which means that it could return `Some z` or a `Some (Some y)`, etc. `f` could return the result with any number of nested `Some`s **depends** on the type of `g`.

---

If I got this question right, it is about function that collapse nested `Some`s. It could be written manually:

```
let collapseOptions x =
    match x with
    | Some (Some y) -> y
    | _ -> None
```

If this question is about function that collapses all nested `Some`s, I'd like to see it's signature :)

Comment: thanks, `collapseOptions` for 2 levels at most is exactly what I needed

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Option.bind`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353901.aspx):

```
let f g x = if x < 0 then None else Option.bind g (Some x)
```

Comment: And how it helps to collapse nested `Some`s?

Comment: @ДМИТРИЙ МАЛИКОВ: Option.bind: ('a -> 'b option) -> 'a option -> 'b option, It returns the result of g(), it applies only to g returns an option

Comment: This approach requires `g` to return `Option 'a` and `bind g (Some x)` is just `g x`.

Answer (score 3):

You have two choices in this case. Either constraint `g` to have type `'a -> Option<'b>` or deal with collapsing the nested option values separately.

The first version:

```
let f (g: int -> Option<'b>) (x: int) = 
    if x < 0 then None else g x
```

In this case, whenever you wish to pass an ordinary function of type `int -> 'b` to `f`, you need to lift it into a function of type `int -> Option<int>`. Here is an example:

```
// Simple function of type: int -> int
let plusOne = (+) 1
let y = f x (pluseOne >> Some)
```

The second alternative is to keep the original definition:

```
let f (g: int -> 'b) (x: int) = if x < 0 then None else Some (g x)
```

and simply collapse the results when desired. This is easily achieved by `Option.bind id` as in:

```
// This function has type: int -> Option<int>
let posPlusOne n = if n < 0 then None else Some (n + 1)
let y = f x posPlusOne |> Option.bind id
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way to fix this would be with a match

```
if x < 0 then
    None
else match g x with
     |Some(t) -> Some(t)
     |None -> None
```

Comment: it seems to be that this code do just `else g x` and nothing more to solve the original question's issue :)

Comment: This approach requires `g` to return `Option 'a` which can be a solution but for some cases it seems like an unnecessary complications because this way only a function that gets `Option 'a` can be used as `g`. I mean in case I want to use a function `g'` that gets a straight `'a` I will have to wrap it to `let g x = Some(g' x)`

Answer (score 2):

Use the maybe monad :

https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpx/blob/master/src/FSharpx.Core/ComputationExpressions/Monad.fs

```
let f g x =
    maybe {
        if x<0 then None
        else
            let! gx = g x
            return f gx }
```